# Equal (ish) areas Map Projection at the Tropics

Tags: coordinate-system, area

What map projection (non-interrupted) preserves areas well for the entire tropical region?
I am thinking of using a Cylindrical Equal Area or a sphere based version of a Cylindrical Equal Area or Mollweide (http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/54009/). My goal is to minimize area distortion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the projections that you cite are equal area, which mean that the projection does not distort the area. Another popular equal area projection is the sinusoidal projection (it is used with MODIS products). Around the equator, cylindrical equal area and sinusoidal are also quite good in terms of shape (Tissot's indicatrice very close to a circle), so these would be good choices. Now it depends if you like perpendicularity between meridians and parallels (cylindrical), or not (sinusoidal)

Comment: Yes, once you've decided upon an Equal Area projection, your area scale is not distorted at all. You need to consider other factors of interest when choosing any _particular_ projection (there are several) from the EA family.